# Unable to solve this geometry problem for math Olympiad preparation for P4 (class 4) in Singapore.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Unable to solve this question after multiple attempts. Could somebody kindly guide me on this problem solution? I am not sure my solution is correct since I make a critical assumption of symmetric structure in the problem ( on page 3 of the solution document pdf attached ).
Need peer review.

Click here for the image of the problem : [Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV0Ch.jpg)

The solution has 3 pages attached as images. See below.

1. Page 1 : [Solution page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU9Qa.jpg)
2. Page 2 : [Solution page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY0E5.jpg)
3. Page 3 : [Solution page 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tzg5.jpg)

Comment: What’s your thoughts? Please show it by editing the post.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) + don't rely on images: [type your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: I have added the solution pages (a total of 3 ). I am not sure if the assumption I have made by studying and pure observation that the symetricity of BG=GC on solutoin page 3 is correct. Rest of the solution approach i am confident. Need peer review if the solution is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$L^2=A_{sq}=A_{rec}/12$

$A_{rec}=4\cdot A_{rec}/12+137.5 cm^2+y$

$2a^2=9L^2$

$2b^2=L^2$

$y=a^2/2+b^2/2$

$2a^2+2b^2=10L^2$

$y=5L^2/2$

$12L^2-5L^2/2-4L^2=137.5cm^2$

$5.5L^2=137.5cm^2$

$L=5cm$

Comment: Can you share a diagram which indicates what your variables like L, Asq, Arec etc mean ?

Comment: I'm not good at drawing. L is the side length of the square. A_sq is the area of one square. A_rec is area of  whole rectangle. a is leg length of the upper left right triangle that is neither shaded nor part of the 4 squares. b is the leg length of the lower left right triangle.  y is the part of the rectangle's area that is neither the 137.5cm^2 nor the 4 squares.